# Who are the Ahle Hadith? Doess Dr. Zakir Naik belong to that sect?

Tags: islamic-scholar, sects

Who are the Ahle Hadiths and how are their practices different from the Sunni Muslims?

I remember that Dr. Zakir Nair mentions in his talks that we should label ourselves as Muslims and not to be divided into sects. Then why is there a new (I suppose) sect by the name of Ahle Hadith that are keen followers of Zakir Naik's bayaans.

Also, why do Dr. Zakir Naik and most of his followers sport a suit with a cap on top? Is this an attire that the Ahle Hadith follows?

**Edit:** I've found an answer to my question of "why do Dr. Zakir Naik and most of his followers sport a suit with a cap on top? Is this an attire that the Ahle Hadith follows?"

Please watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PerGuyP9O94) for more info.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Wa Alaikum As Salam.

*Ahl Al Sunnah* and *Ahl Al Hadith* are both synonymous descriptions that describe Muslims. They are just descriptions.. indicating that these people follow the Sunnah or follow the Hadith. If you are a Muslim with correct Aqeedah & following Islam properly as taught by the Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ), then either of these terms can apply to you.

IF there is any difference, then it is in that 'Ahl Al Hadith' studied hadith more extensively. But again, you don't have to be an hadith expert to fall into this category. Any Muslim who accepts hadith and follows them sincerely is of this group.

Note: Many classical scholars have commented on 'Ahl Al Hadith'. It's not a new term!!

These terms have been used to distinguish ourselves from those who claim to be Muslim yet don't follow Sunnah/Hadith and engage in innovations. Does this contradict the idea of 'just be Muslim'/'don't form sects'? No. Again, they are just description of what it means to be Muslim. - There is no problem in a description. It is of Islam to disassociate yourself from evildoers.

As for Dr. Zakir Naik, he is not a scholar but he's good in comparative religion. Some people from the Ahl Al Hadith movement especially in India may/do respect him a lot, but that doesn't make him the 'face' of Ahl Al Hadith in general. (In other words, whether you follow him or don't follow him doesn't  affect your standing). He personally wears a suit and cap, but the hasn't told anyone else to imitate him nor should anyone else go to great lengths to do so.

Comment: This answer needs a lot of improvement as most of it is simply wrong or based on a wrong understanding. Note there's already a question about AHL al hadith and AHL ar ra'y which answers the given question to the same extent of your partly answer but hopefully with a correct answer. So what needs to be cleared is the issue of Zakir Naik.

Comment: Don't just make claims. Explain what's wrong. It may be that you're the one with the incorrect understanding.

Comment: Ahl al hadith are only a part oft ahl sunnah. I'm not making claims i ve told you about a question that solves your incorrectness. You are messing a school of jursiprudence with a school oft aqeedah.

Comment: @Medi1Saif could you please share the link to that question.

Comment: @Medi1Saif - Um, both are schools of Aqeedah. If Ahl Al Hadith are only part, then who are the others.. referring to "Brelvis" whose Aqeedah differs from the Sunnah/Ahl Al Sunnah? -- Schools of jurisprudence among Ahl Al Sunnah are the Mailikis, Shafiis, Hanbalis and Hanafis.

Comment: Ahl al hadith are school of jurisprudence the most prominent Imams among them were Malik and Imam Ahmad. Ahl as sunnah are ahl al hadith and ahl ar ra'y and when it comes to aqeedah ahl as sunnah are 3 major sects: salafi, ash'arite and maturidi. The salafi view as followed by Malik and Ahmad etc. was good at their time, but not useful later when interfaith discussions came up.

Comment: @DataShark here's the post https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8559/ahlul-hadith-or-ahlul-ray-%d8%a3%d9%87%d9%84-%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%ad%d8%af%d9%8a%d8%ab-%d9%88-%d8%a3%d9%87%d9%84-%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%b1%d8%a3%d9%8a and for a historical development read my answer here https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7427/what-is-the-origin-of-the-concept-of-four-ways-to-follow-islam and here's a sketchy overview on the meaning of salafi https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35631/hanafi-school-considers-male-circumcision-optional-wahabbism-has-a-different-st

Comment: Please read the following scholarly website (Islamweb): "The specific meaning of Ahlus-Sunnah is the antonym of the disbelieving innovators, like the Shiites as well as the Khawaarij, the Jahmiyyah, the Mu‘tazilah, the Murji’ah, the Ashaa‘irah, the Maatureediyyah and others. According to the specific meaning of the term, none of these groups belongs to Ahlus-Sunnah."

Comment: Continues on in detail: http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=38987

Comment: Calling Asharites and Maturidites kuffar is pretty much kufr. Who made this claim?

Comment: You should never build your wisdom on one single source especially if it is a biased site like Islamweb has become the last few years! @G.Bach I assume a salafi who has just repeated what some of "his holy man" has written!

Comment: You incorrectly assumed I built it on one source. I only showed once source that confirms what I said. There are other sources that say the same thing. Moreover,  I don't build my wisdom from random/unknown people like you (or the other guy, who is not even Muslim). Islamweb is reliable and factually correct in this case. How can those who innovate be equal to those who don't? - Use your mind.