# What is Madrasathul Athar and Madrasthul Ra'y?

Tags: fiqh, history, madhhab

I came across these two terms while reading a book and I couldn't fully understand what the book said.

The book said Madrasathul Ra'y was the school of thought of Imam Abu Hanifa Rahimullah and Madrasthul Athar was the school of thought of Imam Malik Rahimullah. Thats all the book said.

I tried to find more information about what are these two things but failed. Google says there are no results for my search and I don't have any other sources.

So can u elaborate on what is Madrasthul Ra'y and what is Madrasathul Athar  ? Whats the difference between these two ?

Jazakallhu Khair

Comment: This is covered in [What is the origin of the four ways to follow Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7427/what-is-the-origin-of-the-concept-of-four-ways-to-follow-islam) and in [Ahlul Hadith or Ahlul Ray -أهل الحديث و أهل الرأي-?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8559/ahlul-hadith-or-ahlul-ray-%d8%a3%d9%87%d9%84-%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%ad%d8%af%d9%8a%d8%ab-%d9%88-%d8%a3%d9%87%d9%84-%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%b1%d8%a3%d9%8a). Please check this post and give feedback.